# OpenSSL from ports in PHP 5.6 / FreeBSD

Tags: php, openssl, freebsd

Can't get OpenSSL from ports to work in PHP. FreeBSD 9.1.

php -i shows:

```
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Base system openssl:

```
# /usr/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
```

Ports openssl:

```
# /usr/local/bin/openssl version

    WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/openssl/openssl.cnf
    OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Module seems to be linked against proper library:

```
# ldd /usr/local/lib/php/20131226-zts/openssl.so
/usr/local/lib/php/20131226-zts/openssl.so:
    libssl.so.8 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.8 (0x801224000)
# strings /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.8 | grep OpenSSL
OpenSSLDie
SSLv2 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
SSLv3 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
DTLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Need help understansing why php -i shows OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8x

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

Skimming through PHP sources reveal that library version is obtained with function call:

```
php_info_print_table_row(2, "OpenSSL Library Version", SSLeay_version(SSLEAY_VERSION));
```

And header version is a preprocessor constant, which gets compiled into the extension:

```
php_info_print_table_row(2, "OpenSSL Header Version", OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT);
```

You've probably updated `openssl` port, got a new version of the library, and because its ABI haven't changed everything works for you. But since you didn't recompile the extension itself, the `OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT` constant have value from the old header.

If you really worry about this you can rebuild `php56-openssl` port, but since maintainers haven't bumped it during `openssl` update, i think it is a harmless thing.